# Invalid syntax in expression using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-python-console

I am trying to calculate VCI using NDVI values in QGIS Python Console. I am getting invalid syntax for my expression.

```
layer1 = NDVI_layer
layer1 = iface.activeLayer()
idx = layer1.fields().indexFromName("mean")
min1 = layer1.minimumValue(idx)
print (min1)
max1 = layer1.maximumValue(idx)
print (max1)

layer2 = layer1
layer_provider1=layer2.dataProvider()
layer_provider1.addAttributes([QgsField("VCI",QVariant.Double)

ex1 = QgsExpression('(("mean"-min1)/(max1-min1))')
```

Comment: Please include your error message to this post.

Comment: @GBG It is Invalid syntax for ex1 (expression)

Answer (score 8):

You can use Python f-string syntax for the expression.

Use

```
ex1 = QgsExpression(f"(mean - {min1}) / ({max1} - {min1})")
```

Python f-string is the newest Python syntax to do string formatting. Python f-strings provide a faster, more readable, more concise, and less error-prone way of formatting strings in Python[<sup>1</sup>](https://zetcode.com/python/fstring/). **But it is available since Python 3.6**. So this solution doesn't work in old versions of QGIS using older Python versions.

Answer (score 7):

You need to `format` your expression :

```
expression = '( ( "mean" - {min1} ) / ( {max1} - {min1} ) )'.format(min1=min1, max1=max1)
print(expression)  # To let's you check what you have
ex1 = QgsExpression(expression)
```

You were not replacing your min and max. It was just a plain string.

You can use f-string : `f'( "mean" - {min1} ) / ( {max1} - {min1} )'`, it's more readable but it's available only in Python **3.6**. So it's not sure that you won't have an issue on some QGIS version running an old Python version. Python **3.6** is only required with QGIS **3.18**.